# Error catching, can I interrupt and stop the process?

Tags: java

I have a java servlet and have written a method that will let the client know that the server has encountered an error with the given input.

The client then calls a method called `handleErrors()`

What I'd like to do is for this method to stop the process that has sent the request to the server. Would a thread interrupt be of use here or is their a better practice for dealing with errors like these?

Here is a shortened overview:

Server:

Expects a string that is formatted like this: "ab££" - 2 characters, 2 symbols

Client:

Sends: badMethod() sends "££££"

Server:

Returns: "Error"

Client:

Realizes error and runs handleErrorMethod() which would stop badMethod() completely.

I hope this is a clear question and not a dupe.

TIA

Comment: Surely your server side method has stopped when it's sent the error message? Why would the client need to call another method to stop it any more?

Comment: Yes the server has finished its work, but the method was expecting a specific return and if it carries on without that return it will cause an error. I have many methods like this, I'd like a way to stop any methods that are excuting when handleErrorMethod() is called.

Comment: Have `badMethod` do its stuff in a separate thread, keeping a reference to this thread in a some global (static) collection, then `handleErrorMethod` can grab from the collection the set of threads to interrupt.

Comment: Still don't understand sorry, maybe post a real world example?

Comment: What are the client and server techonolgies being used is it Spring, Play Framework or just plain IO Sockets?

Comment: Have handleErrors() throw an exception.

Comment: But this doesn't stop the previous method executing does it? It will throw my new exception then throw its own ones as well?

Comment: @EricBanderhide Of course it does. The exception stops everything until the catch block that catches it. Your last sentence is meaningless to me.

Comment: I've tried it a few ways and although I can throw a new error and catch it, once that's done it just goes on to the other errors without stopping execution. Have you got an example?

Comment: @EricBanderhide You must have some very strange code. Clearly you are catching the exception in the wrong place. Catch it *after* the code you want to avoid when it is thrown. Surely this is obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a RESTful service, the typical flow would involve the server returning an HTTP error status in the 400 range (422 might be a good fit here), which your client should inspect and respond accordingly.  Your use of "Error" in the message payload should still work, but you might consider some existing standards.  Once the client has its response, though, the server is out of the loop and all the programming is local to the client.

So, if the client is also written in Java (I hate to assume), then you could use any number of techniques.  The suggestion by @EJP to have handleErrors() in the client throw an exception seems like a simple, elegant solution to me.  Your calling method, badMethod(), would be interrupted and could either catch the exception or bubble the exception to its caller.